# Retorno Errado sobre função SE

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=SE(C5<=3,09;"0,15%";SE(C5<=3,1--4,99;"0,20%";SE(C5>=5;C5;"0,30%")))
```

esta retornando valor errado na ultima função

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você quer dizer com esta condição: C5<=3,1--4,99? Talvez você queira: E(C5>=3,1; C5<=4,99)

Comment: ENTAO FICOU MENOR IGUAL A 3,1 ATE 4,99 PARA RETORNAR 0,30%

Comment: Maior ou igual a 3,1 e menor ou igual a 4,9 retorna "0,20%".

Comment: Note que em seu último SE nunca será exibido o resultado "0,30%".

Comment: Talvez seja melhor você descrever o que deseja fazer e a fórmula utilizada e o que considera que está errado.

Comment: CORRIGINDO A FORMULA E ESSA

Comment: =SE(C5<=3,09;"0,15%";SE(C5<=3,1--4,99;"0,20%";SE(C5>=5;"0,30%")))

Comment: QUERO QUE RETORNE 0,30% QUANDO FOR 5 MAS NAO RETORNA ELE RETORNAR 0,30 APARTIR DE 8

Comment: =SE(C5<=3,09;"0,15%";SE(C5<=3,1;"0,20%";SE(C5<=4,99;"0,20%";SE(C5>=5;"0,30%"))))     VALEI JA ACHEI UMA FORMA DE DAR CERTO

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar as **referências** das células. Assim conseguiremos te ajudar...

Em todos os casos tente o seguinte:

```
SE(C5<=3,09;"0,15%";SE(C5<=3,1;"0,20%";SE(C5<5;"0,20%";SE(C5>=5;"0,30%"))))
```

Assim é possível contemplar todos os **valores menores que 5**